# facebook connect Phonegap api

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api

I'm having a issue with accessing the Facebook connect Graph API, I have used [this plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin), the login example works great and share example also works fine.

I have a problem getting a response from the Facebook API to work.

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fb_info").click(function() {
        facebookConnectPlugin.api("/me",
            function (response) {
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: yep just says alert ( error error )

Comment: Are you able to attach a debugger to get more information? Or maybe PhoneGap has a way to debug errors so you can see the full error message and stack trace.